# Is it possible to have a dynamic resource path for import?

Tags: spring.net

I have a Spring.NET program with a configuration file.  To smooth the transition from test to prod I'd like to have an environment variable that gives the path to a shared config file, and use that to [import a resource](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-xml-import), however it appears the `<import resource="path"/>` is not being [resolved](http://springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-placeholderconfigurer).  For example if I try to load the file `<import resource="\\server\share\${computername}\SpringConfig.xml"/>` I get a file not found exception as below:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error creating context 'spring.root': file [\server\share\${computername}\SpringConfig.xml] cannot be resolved to local file path - resource does not use 'file:' protocol. ---> Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from file [\server\share\${computername}\SpringConfig.xml] ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: file [\server\share\${computername}\SpringConfig.xml] cannot be resolved to local file path - resource does not use 'file:' protocol.

Is there a way I can have a dynamic import path in Spring.NET, preferably without writing code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that anyway with some extra code:

- Create your own FileSystemResource that will replace placeholders in the resource name. Start from overriding the existing FileSystemResource (In Spring.Core.IO namespace)
- Register your new IResource implementation in the container using your own protocol name (ex: myfile://) See ref docs here for an example :

  1. In .NET configuration file (app.config/web.config)
     http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/resources.html#d4e2911
  2. In Spring configuration files
     http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#context-custom-resourcehandler
- Use it!
  resource="myfile://\server\share\${computername}\SpringConfig.xml"

Comment: Cool, I'll have to try it out.  I also created a [Jira Feature Request](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPRNET-1491), not sure I followed the right process though...

Comment: Thanks!  That's was pleasantly simple to implement, though the constructor requirements weren't well documented.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we can do that with the current version.
Latest Java version supports it, so we can expect this feature in a future version (Using variables environnement by default)

Comment: Any idea what code I would need to write to make this magic happen?