# Spring.NET Load a spring context relative to the directory of the assembly

Tags: spring.net

I'd like to specify a context resource relative to the location of the calling assembly (in this case, it should be Spring.Core.dll).  The default is relative to the execution path, causing file not found issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems spring hasn't build in a resource locator with the functionality you expect, but you can build your own implementing the [IResource](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/resources.html#objects-iresource) interface.

Comment: This is the way to go; good point to get started is bbaia's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9324452/322283

Comment: I saw the same answer and was hoping that I don't need to implement my own.